# Trigger form submission with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form that I would like to submit via JavaScript. Obviously this can be achieved by:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

The issue is that I have a listener on the `submit` event that looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Other work
});
```

This event handler is not triggered when I call `.submit()`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit):

> The form's onsubmit event handler (for example, onsubmit="return
>   false;") will not be triggered when invoking this method from
>   Gecko-based applications. In general, it is not guaranteed to be
>   invoked by HTML user agents.

So, given this restraint, how can I submit the form in a way that ensures the event handler is invoked?

Comment: Just call [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) alongside your `.submit()` call

Comment: What is the proper way to to call `dispatchEvent`? According to MDN, `dispatchEvent` is supported across browsers, but calling `new Event()` is not. How else can an event be constructed?

Comment: probably something in line of `var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
evt.initEvent("submit", true, true); form.dispatchEvent(evt);` [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975247(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need create a submit event, then dispatch it.

```
(function () {
              if ( typeof window.CustomEvent === "function" ) return false;

              function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
                params = params || { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, detail: undefined };
                var evt = document.createEvent('submit');
                evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
                return evt;
               }

              CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

              window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;

})();
var evt = new CustomEvent("submit", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable": true});
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit",function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('submit');
});
```

Then when you want submit this function you need to call:

```
!document.getElementById("myForm").dispatchEvent(evt);
```

For more event info see [dispatchEvent.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

Comment: According to MDN, `new Event` is not supported in IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event

Comment: @Max, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent ,here have a common methed to deal with IE > 9

Answer (score 22):

**Update Nov 21, 2022**

I would now recommend the `requestSubmit()` method. You can pass a submit button to it if you want. Its cleaner and can be intercepted.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").requestSubmit();
```

**Original answer**

A custom event works just fine.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('submit', {cancelable: true}));
```

Answer (score -11):

Use jQuery to submit the form and add the handler.

```js
$("#myForm").on("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // Handle submission here
});

// Then later
$("#myForm").submit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not using jQuery.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, if your trying to run some code after the form is submitted, and your submitting the form using JavaScript, then why not just run the code after you submit the code using JavaScript

Comment: I've decided to run to code after submitting the form with JavaScript. It's just somewhat annoying that you can't trigger the submit handler via `.submit()`.

Comment: And that is exactly why people use jQuery. Because each browser has it's little quarks as to what works and what doesn't, and jQuery makes all features work on all browsers.

Comment: The `.submit()` works without jQuery too. For example, `document.querySelector('form').submit();` works perfectly!