# Trigger onSubmit from submit function

Tags: javascript, php, html, submit, onsubmit

Is it possible to trigger onSubmit event of the form by calling it with

```
function submitEdit(){
    document.getElementById("edit").submit();
};
```

**THIS WAY IS NOT WORKING**

Form:

```
echo "<form id='edit' onsubmit='validate(flag, typeFlag)' method='post' style='width: 100%;height:86%;'>";`
```

onSubmit event:

```
window.flag=false;
var typeFlag;

    function validate(flag, typeFlag) { 
        if   ( (flag==true) && (typeFlag==true) ){
            document.getElementById("edit").setAttribute('target', '_self');
            document.getElementById("edit").action ="date.php";
        } else if ( (flag==true) && (typeFlag==false) ){
            document.getElementById("edit").setAttribute('target', '_blank');
            document.getElementById("edit").action ="date_PDF.php"; 
        } else
            alert("Select an aircraft");
    }
```

Am I doing it right? I need to submit this form by clicking on a radio button.

```
echo '<td class="c3" style="color: #f79393">
                                <div class="radio">
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="name_check" onclick="typeFlag=true; submitEdit();" class="c3" value="in" id="c3" '; if($flag) echo'checked'; echo '>in</label>
                                </div>
                              </td>';
```

Thank You!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger form submission with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154348/trigger-form-submission-with-javascript)

Comment: Wbat does "not working" mean? What happens instead? What have you tried to find the error?

Comment: Page is refreshing and nothing happens. How to simulate  submitting form with onSubmit function with parameters (flag, typeFlag)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **2022 UPDATE**

This post is old, but I might as well leave a new working solution. It appears that `requestSubmit()` does exactly what OP needed. [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit)

The updated function:

```js
function submitEdit(){
    document.getElementById("edit").requestSubmit();
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Manually 'submit' function on form doesn't trigger 'submit' event so you have to trigger it.

```js
function submitEdit(){

var ele = document.getElementById('edit');
    ele.submit();
  

var event = new Event('submit', {
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
});
ele.dispatchEvent(event);

}
submitEdit();

function validate() {
  console.log('form submitted');
}
```

```html
<form id='edit' onsubmit='validate()' method='post' style='width: 100%;height:86%;'>
<input type='text' value='name'/>
</form>
```

Comment: `echo '<td class="c3" style="color: #f79393">
          <div class="radio">
           <label><input type="radio" name="name_check" onclick="typeFlag=true; submitEdit();" class="c3" value="in" id="c3" '; if($flag) echo'checked'; echo '>in</label>
          </div>
          </td>';` Do I call it in a right way?

Comment: When I insert this code to my php there is error in GoogleChrome `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null
    at submitEdit (calendar.php?date=01-07-2018&num=&date1=01-07-2018&but=Go:41)
    at calendar.php?date=01-07-2018&num=&date1=01-07-2018&but=Go:53`

Comment: @Vanfen you have to put this code into (function(){ paste above code here })(); because maybe the form element is not available before calling submit event on it. Or first, check if ele is printing in the console. The error is telling that it is not able to get form element using that 'edit' id. You have to be sure that you are calling submit function on the form element.

Comment: Experimenting with this, it seems to submit the form early. For example, if my handler pops an ok/cancel confirmation dialog, this will begin the submission before the dialog is shown and gets submitted regardless of which button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to trigger onSubmit with .submit()?**

No, it is not possible, `validate()` function never going to be fired. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) about `submit()` :

> When invoking this method directly, no submit event is raised (in
>   particular, the form's onsubmit event handler is not run),  and
>   constraint validation is not triggered either.

Then, since you don't have an `action` attribute in your `<form>`, when you execute `document.getElementById("edit").submit();` nothing happens.