# Why does the second eventlistener not fire?

Tags: javascript, submit, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have two event listeners on my page, but the second one does not fire when I click the button. How do I get the submit event listener to fire?

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
});
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("submit triggered")
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input><br>
  <button id="myButton" type="button">Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You could simulate a submission event but I don't think this is a sensible way to go here, I'm more curious about the actual problem you're trying to solve. Why do you have two event listeners in the first place? (Also note that calling `submit()` on the form does not trigger the event, just cause the actual submission, which here reloads the page)

Comment: There is no submit event raised when you call `FormElement.submit()`. Why not just use `type="submit"` on the button and remove the .submit() call?

Comment: A submission started from JS doesn't trigger a submit event. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63509329/1169519

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger form submission with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154348/trigger-form-submission-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20090323062817/http://blogs.vertigosoftware.com/snyholm/archive/2006/09/27/3788.aspx), 'submit' event fires when user submits a form not when you submit a form using script.

> Current browsers do not adhere to this part of the html specification. The event only fires when it is activated by a user - and does not fire when activated by code.