# Internet Explorer issue with HTML5 form attribute for button element

Tags: jquery, html

in HTML5, there is the form attribute. Basically

```
<form id="myform" method="get" action="something.jsp">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>
<input type="submit" form="myform" />
```

the above code is not working in IE.
Can any one help me how to solve this requirement.

I've used the following javascript and jQuery to submit the form, but I facing the Ajax issue.
where my page is reloading.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

$("#myForm").submit();
```

How can I submit my form where my page should not load.
I am using Anguler JS Ajax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to support/shim button form attribute in IE10?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694195/any-way-to-support-shim-button-form-attribute-in-ie10)

Comment: As the answers indicate, IE does not support this.  But you could vote to change that: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/7327649-add-support-for-the-form-attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [polyfill html5 input "form" attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742275/polyfill-html5-input-form-attribute)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

IE does not support HTML5 `form` attribute for `<input>` or `<button>` element yet.

If you want to associate an outer input element with the form, you can duplicate a "shadow" as an invisible input field inside your form, and attach an event handler to the form's `onsubmit` event. When user submits the form, update the value inside.

The following polyfill (requires jQuery) emulates the feature. It makes the input elements with `form` attribute act like they are inside the form:

```
(function($) {
  /**
   * polyfill for html5 form attr
   */

  // detect if browser supports this
  var sampleElement = $('[form]').get(0);
  var isIE11 = !(window.ActiveXObject) && "ActiveXObject" in window;
  if (sampleElement && window.HTMLFormElement && sampleElement.form instanceof HTMLFormElement && !isIE11) {
    // browser supports it, no need to fix
    return;
  }

  /**
   * Append a field to a form
   *
   */
  $.fn.appendField = function(data) {
    // for form only
    if (!this.is('form')) return;

    // wrap data
    if (!$.isArray(data) && data.name && data.value) {
      data = [data];
    }

    var $form = this;

    // attach new params
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      $('<input/>')
        .attr('type', 'hidden')
        .attr('name', item.name)
        .val(item.value).appendTo($form);
    });

    return $form;
  };

  /**
   * Find all input fields with form attribute point to jQuery object
   * 
   */
  $('form[id]').submit(function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    // serialize data
    var data = $('[form='+ $form.attr('id') + ']').serializeArray();
    // append data to form
    $form.appendField(data);
  }).each(function() {
    var form = this,
      $form = $(form),
      $fields = $('[form=' + $form.attr('id') + ']');

    $fields.filter('button, input').filter('[type=reset],[type=submit]').click(function() {
      var type = this.type.toLowerCase();
      if (type === 'reset') {
        // reset form
        form.reset();
        // for elements outside form
        $fields.each(function() {
          this.value = this.defaultValue;
          this.checked = this.defaultChecked;
        }).filter('select').each(function() {
          $(this).find('option').each(function() {
            this.selected = this.defaultSelected;
          });
        });
      } else if (type.match(/^submit|image$/i)) {
        $(form).appendField({name: this.name, value: this.value}).submit();
      }
    });
  });


})(jQuery);
```

Live version: http://jsfiddle.net/hbxk4e61/

By the way, you can check [this page](http://html5test.com/) to test how many HTML5 features your browser currently supports. For example, I'm using Chrome 31 and it does support this attribute.

[image: Chrome currently supports the feature]

Comment: Why is this post upvoted? It doesn't answer the OP's question, and the first link is to W3schools (which is bad enough) which doesn't provide any info as to browser support for this attribute.

Comment: @Makita `IE does not support HTML5 form attribute for of element yet.` is my answer.

Comment: Your answer does not address the question. You might as well have answered "42". At least vergillus' answer provides a solution.

Comment: @Makita I wrote the code to achieve the feature. If you found any issue, leaving a comment will be appreciated.

Comment: 2016 and this answer is still relevant.

Comment: Yep, this caused an embarrassing code demo. Stupid IE.

Answer (score 5):

Well, IE basically does not support form attribute in input, but you could use javascript to submit your form:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

or jQuery

```
$("#myForm").submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form id="form-any-name">
   <input type="button" value="Submit" class="myButton" />
</form>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button[type=\'submit\']').on('click', function() {
            $("form[id*='form-']").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Since all projects has included jquery 100%  :) you can define in external or any included js file the on document ready function  to catch the submit button clicked outsiie form by catching all forms  id starting with form-   so it catch forms on different page with different names so you do not have to repeat the very same jquery code snipet

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, Internet Explorer does not (up to IE10, at least) support the `form` attribute.

You can either polyfill this in javascript, or move the `input` to sit inside the relevant form. This has already been answered elsewhere though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16694990/13019

Answer (score 1):

From @Voldemaras Birškys' answer, I've improved his script to work as a polyfill so you can still have the `form` attribute no your button and it will work as if EDGE/IE would respect the `form` attribute.

```
<form id="form-any-name">
   <input type="button" value="Submit" class="myButton" />
</form>
<button type="submit" form="form-any-name">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button[type=\'submit\']').click(function (e) {
        var formId = $(e.target).attr("form");
        $("form[id*="+formId+"]").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

The main difference is that now we include `form` on the external `submit` button.
Also, inside the `click` handler I just use the event to get the `target` element and from id discover the `id` of the target form.

:)

Comment: This and @Voldemaras Birškys answers are the best. No other fancy solutions required, guys! Of course IE being, well, IE :) we need to be prepared for this kind of issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you send form via ajax and use vanilla js, you can add inputs with "form" attribute like below:

```
function sendViaAjax(event, callback) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = event.target;
    var formId = form.id;
    var url = form.getAttribute('action');
    var method = form.getAttribute('method');
    var data = new FormData(form);
    if(isInternetExplorer() && formId) {
        var formInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[form="'+formId+'"], textarea[form="'+formId+'"], select[form="'+formId+'"]');
        [].forEach.call(formInputs, function (el) {
            var inputName = el.getAttribute('name');
            data.append(inputName, el.value);
        });
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        // something
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
       // something
    };
    xhr.send(data);
}

function isInternetExplorer() {
    return (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ||
        !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) ||
            navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:11/)) ||
        (typeof $.browser !== "undefined" && $.browser.msie == 1));
}
```