# attr not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm a newbie to JQuery. I'm trying to add "input" tag to form in different select case.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select[name=InputSource]").change(function() {
            if (this.value == 3) {
                eth_input = true;
                $(".page_ip").attr("form", "broadcastform");
            } else {
                eth_input = false;
                $(".page_ip").attr("form", "");
            }
        });
    });
```

But attr seems not working for IE. I search for article that people suggest to use data-* with IE browser. But problem is that I still need to change "form" attribute in order to make this input into the form. Is there anyway to apply attr to change "form" attribute?

Comment: yes. In chrome and firefox, it works fine. but in IE, I check the console there is nothing change.

Comment: put in code in fiddle ..

Comment: @Pwan: We can't answer your question without more context. I suggest creating a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button). `attr` should work with the [`form` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fae-form).

Comment: @Pwan: My mistake, we can: This is probably a duplicate of [*Internet Explorer issue with HTML5 form attribute for button element*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658402/internet-explorer-issue-with-html5-form-attribute-for-button-element) - IE doesn't support the `form` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that the `form` attribute isn't being applied by your code. It's that [IE doesn't support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute) (not even IE11). [Details and possible workaround in this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658402/internet-explorer-issue-with-html5-form-attribute-for-button-element) (and other questions and their answers linked to it).

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: Thank you. For some reason when I went there and typed "form," that didn't show up. (Which is odd, as I just tried doing so again, and it did.)

Comment: I did't know that. How can I added an input attribute to a form if IE is not supported form attribute?

Comment: @Pwan: See the linked question, the other questions linked to it, and their answers.

Comment: T.J i'm your fan!!

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the javascript setAttribute instead Jquery. See the
>   support here: http://caniuse.com/#search=setAttribute
>   Add:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

along with `<!DOCTYPE html>`

> It works in IE8+ environments

Comment: Isn't that what jQuery's `.attr()` method uses behind the scenes?

Comment: Could be.  Need to check the Jquery API. You need to add the meta tag too. Added in my answer. It works in IE8+ envirnoments.

Answer (score 0):

Its because form attribute is part of HTML5 and is not supported by IE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input.

This had hppened with me when I tried to add/change few ARIA attrs which are not supported by IE. Though form attr's usage can be ignored by wrapping up in a separate form and appended after the previous form. And position it at desired place.

Your code snippet is not helping very much as the markup/html is also required to suggest better solution.